# Sprockets at deploy time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, stylesheet, sprockets, precompile

I have read the following sentence in the book 'Rails 4 in Action'.

> But when it comes to deployment, you’ll be using Sprockets to compile
>   stylesheets just once, at deploy time, so any changes you made to
>   states after deployment would not be reflected on your site.

But I don't understand why changes are not reflected on the production site. If I stop the production server, deploy new changes to it and restart the server again, then all the stylesheets would get compiled again, don't they?

What does the author of the book mean by the sentence? Could you enlighten me on this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, If there is any change in your assets they will be precompiled during the deployment and will take effect once you restart you server.